# hide home indicator for iPhone X

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-x

i have an iOS app with video player, when the video is playing (landscape, full screen) i would like to hide the home indicator on iPhone X. I have try with

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
     [self setNeedsUpdateOfHomeIndicatorAutoHidden];
}
```

and also

```
-(BOOL)prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden{
   return YES;
}
```

but no luck. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: `prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden` worked in landscape for me in a new test project. Is there any other relevant code or information about your view controller?

Answer (score 7):

> When implementing a container view controller, override
>   [childViewControllerForHomeIndicatorAutoHidden()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2887508-childviewcontrollerforhomeindica) method if you want
>   one your child view controllers to determine whether to display the
>   visual indicator. If you do, the system calls the
>   prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden() method of the returned view
>   controller. If the method returns nil, the system calls the
>   prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden() method of the current view controller

So if you are using `childViewController` then need to implement `childViewControllerForHomeIndicatorAutoHidden`
as -

**Swift**

```
extension UINavigationController {
    open override func childViewControllerForHomeIndicatorAutoHidden() -> UIViewController? {
        return DemoViewController.loadFromNib()
    }
}

//DemoViewController is childViewController
class DemoViewController: UIViewController {
    static func loadFromNib() -> DemoViewController{
        let storyBoardInst = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        return storyBoardInst.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DemoViewController") as! DemoViewController
    }

    override func prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            //Notifies UIKit that your view controller updated its preference regarding the visual indicator
            setNeedsUpdateOfHomeIndicatorAutoHidden()
        }
    }
}
```

**Objective C-**

```
@interface UINavigationController(custom)
@end
@implementation UINavigationController(custom)
-(UIViewController *)childViewControllerForHomeIndicatorAutoHidden{
    return [self.storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DemoViewController"];
}
@end
    //DemoViewController is childViewController
@interface DemoViewController ()
@end
@implementation DemoViewController
-(BOOL)prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden{
    return YES;
}
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    //Notifies UIKit that your view controller updated its preference 
    // regarding the visual indicator
    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        [self setNeedsUpdateOfHomeIndicatorAutoHidden];
    }
}
```

Output -

[image]